# In Jira, Agile board , sprint plan mode, what are the blue, yellow and green time bubbles?

Tags: jira, agile

In Jira, Agile board , sprint plan mode, what are the blue, yellow and green time bubbles? They list times ( 2w 5d) , but don't say what they are for. They don't seem to add up to statuses "in progress", "done" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total time estimate is based on the columns To Do, In Progress and Done of the board just like JIRA Agile Sprint Health Gadget.

Reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Using+the+Sprint+Health+Gadget